# Outlook 2007 Meetings/Appointments

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

Just curious why when I view others schedule and hover over a portion where they have an allocated time for something I am able to see the subject of it, however when viewing others I cannot see the subject.

Is their some sort of outlook setting that lets your meeting information become viewable by the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark appointments in Outlook as "private" which would prevent you from seeing the subject.